# Order table by presences in a third table

Tags: mysql

I have a movie database with a table for actors and another one for movies, I created a third table to add an actor partecipation in a movie. I added a field "star" to distinque leading actors from not leading actors.
I wish create a list order by the actors importance and so by the the total number of "stars".

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT( p.star ) AS star
FROM actors a
JOIN playing p, movies m
WHERE p.id_actor = a.id
AND p.id_movie = m.id
AND p.star =1
GROUP BY p.star
ORDER BY p.star DESC;
```

**ACTORS**

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | actor01 |
|  2 | actor02 |
|  3 | actor03 |
+----+---------+
```

**MOVIES**

```
+----+----------+
| id |  title   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | movie01  |
|  2 | movie02  |
|  3 | movie03  |
+----+----------+
```

**PLAYING**

```
+----------+----------+-------+------+
| id_movie | id_actor | char  | star |
+----------+----------+-------+------+
|        1 |        1 | char1 |    0 |
|        1 |        2 | char2 |    1 |
|        2 |        3 | char3 |    1 |
+----------+----------+-------+------+
```

I Need output Like:

```
+----------+--------------+
|    actor |  protagonist |
+----------+--------------+
|  actor01 |    2 times   |
|  actor02 |    3 times   |
+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please add your expected output

Comment: Don't mix implicit (comma) join and explicit JOIN syntax. In fact, don't use comma-join at all - at least not until you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @Strawberry not even if you know what you're doing

Comment: @bohemian Well, the cross join on the ranking trick's OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the `group by` clause to group by the *actor* not the *star* column.  You need to fix the `order by` to group by the aggregated column, not the original column:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, sum( p.star = 1) AS stars
FROM actors a join playing p
     on p.id_actor = a.id join
     movies m
     on p.id_movie = m.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY stars DESC;
```

Along the way, I fixed the `from` so it uses proper `join` syntax (with an `on` clause). And changed the query so it returns all actors, even those who have never been the star.

Comment: You are nice Gordon - no getting away from that.

Answer (score 1):

1.If you want to count all stars for an actor, you should group by actor but not stars.(Unless you want to count how many times an actor gets 1 star in a movie, you may not want to group by star)

2.You may want to use `ON` with `JOIN`

3.You may want to `ORDER BY star` but not `ORDER BY p.star` since you want to order by the result.

4.You may want to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` to get the star counts.(`SUM` calculates the value but `COUNT` calculates the number. With `SUM`, you can set star value to whatever you want without change your sql. You can have star=2 which shows the actor is important to the movie or have star=-1, which means the actor stinks.)

You may have a look at the sql below:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, SUM( p.star ) AS sum
FROM actors a
LEFT JOIN playing p ON p.id_actor = a.id
LEFT JOIN movies m ON p.id_movie = m.id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY sum DESC;
```